# Ubuntu Full Screen Freeze 16.04

Tags: google-chrome, freeze, fullscreen

It is not just when exiting YouTube full screen. It is any type of full screen video, picture, power point slide show. It happens a lot.
It happens like 5 times a day for me, and it is driving me crazy.

I noticed from google research that many people are suffering from the same problem as well; however, there is no solid solution to this.

I've tried using google chrome beta version and have hardware acceleration unchecked.

If anyone knows how to get this solved, please let me know.
I've been looking around for an answer for this over few months already.

Comment: Do you have the correct/latest video driver installed? How much RAM? How much swap? In `terminal` type `free -h` and paste that output into your question.

Comment: total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        2.5G         11G        336M        2.0G         12G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B

Comment: Though I don't have Swap, I have a big Memory. Will it matter whether I have Swap or not?

Comment: Yes, you need swap. 8G would probably be enough, or 17G if you have hibernation enabled. Did you also check on your video driver?

Comment: how can I check for video driver update?

Comment: Go to the manufacturer's web site with the model number of your video card (or computer), and go to the support section, and look there for downloads or driver updates. Check for BIOS updates while you're there.

Comment: thank you so much! I will try to do the Swap space and come back for the result!

Comment: Been an hour trying to break the screen, but it works good so far. Thank you!

Comment: Swap helped, great! Did you do a swap file, or a swap partition? I threw together a quick answer. Please vote/accept it if you think it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments...

You need to enable a swap file or swap partition. 8G should work, or 17G if you have hibernation enabled.

Also check the manufacturer's web site for BIOS updates, and video driver updates.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please **vote** by clicking the grey up-arrow icon in the upper-left of my answer, and **accept** my answer by clicking the grey checkmark icon in the upper-left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, as I was watching youtube today, it crashed again...
same thing, I had to force shut down my laptop and boot again.
I got myself 32G swap partition, and it is still doing the same thing.

Comment: 32G swap is probably excessive, and a lot more than I recommended. That's not your problem now though. Go ahead and check for BIOS and video updates. The BIOS will come from the manufacturer's web site, and the video may come from Nvidea/AMD/whatever.